# Grails UI for GSPs

Tags: user-interface, grails, grails-plugin

i nearly finished the functions of my application but i'm not happy with the UI  standard Grails `GSPs`, i needed to change it to something simple and colorful , is there any recommended UI framework to be used with Grails other than `BootStrap` may help me in achieving this , appreciate your recommendations .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Pure](http://purecss.io/) by Yahoo? You can use [Pure CSS Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/pure-css) with Grails.

Other options could be:

- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) by Zurb
- [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)
- [UIkit](http://getuikit.com/) by YOOtheme